# PdfDocument - Cut page at the end of the layout

Tags: android, pdf-generation, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a Pdf file using the Android [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) class. I'm inflating the layout from an XML file (a *LinearLayout* inside a *ConstraintLayout*), which is then completed at run-time by adding new rows with external data.

The problem is that the output pdf can be very long or short. I would like to avoid specifying the page height before inflating the layout. However, I can't find a solution to measure the height of the layout before adding it to the page

This is the actual code:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

//set page width and height
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(227,992, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

//inflating the layout
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rapportino, null);

//add data to layout
//...

//measure the layout, draw it and finish page
int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.getCanvas().getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.getCanvas().getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
v.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight);
v.layout(0, 0, measureWidth, measuredHeight);
v.draw(page.getCanvas());
document.finishPage(page);

//write to file..
```

Is there a way to create the pdf depending on the height of the view?

**EDIT:** this is the layout i'm inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rapportino_indirizzo_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rapportino_global_textsize" />

        <!-- 
            other textview, linearlayout and imageview 
            ..
            ..  
        -->

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`?

Comment: Yes, I applied the *makeMeasureSpec* method to `v.getWidth()` and `v.getHeight()`. With `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` it returns 0 and 0, with `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` it returns 1073741824 and 1073741824, which don't seem usable values!

Comment: Can you post your xml file?

Comment: I edited the question, thanks! Sorry, I did not remember that the *LinearLayout* was in a *ConstraintLayout*. It was only because otherwise the pdf did not take the margins (don't know why). Anyway, even if I remove the constraint layout it does not work.

Comment: Can you try putting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the pdf container and remove `measure ` and `layout` method?

Comment: Yes, it still gives me 0x0 with `View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` and 1073741824x1073741824 with `View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`. The problem is that that `v.getWidth()` and `v.getHeight()` always return 0!

Comment: yes, but by removing `measure()` and `layout()`, you don't need to care about width and height of view right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. What I'm trying to do is:  
1. inflate the layout and populate it with data
2. calculate the height
3. create the pdf page with that height.

If I'm not mistaken, the inflated layout will have height of 0 until it is assigned with `measure()`. However, if both the `makeMeasureSpec(..)` and `v.getHeight()` methods give me a value of 0, how can I create a page with the right dimension?

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the height? Just let Android do it for you

Comment: I'm not familiar with `PdfDocument`, but I think `v.draw(page.getCanvas());` will do the job for you already

Comment: I need to calculate the height because when page.getCanvas () becomes available the page has already been created and the dimensions have already been specified. However, at the moment I solved in another way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved with a quite strange solution. Since adding a layout to a view causes the height to be calculated, I created an *invisible* view in the activity where I'm creating the pdf (with the width of the pdf):

```
<!-- add this to your activity -->
<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/output_pdf_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="226dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then I added the inflated layout to the invisible view (after having filled it with external data). With an observer you can get the height at the time it is calculated.

```
//inflating the layout
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rapportino, null);

//add data to layout (rows, images etc.)
//...

//find the invisible view
LinearLayout invisibleOutputPdfView = findViewById(R.id.output_pdf_view);

//add the pdf layout and observe changes
invisibleOutputPdfView.addView(v);
invisibleOutputPdfView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //remove the listener
            invisibleOutputPdfView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            int height = invisibleOutputPdfView.getHeight();
            createPDF(height, ..);
        }
    });
```

NOTE: for some reason it seems that there is a 1:1 ratio between *dp* and *pt* in the generation of the pdf. So no conversions are needed.